# Has the Roelcke completion of a topological group any reasonable algebraic structure?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, uniform-spaces

It is well-known that each topological group $G$ carries (at least) four natural uniformities:

the *left uniformity* $\mathcal L$, generated by the base $\{\{(x,y)\in G\times G:y\in xU\}:U\in\mathcal \tau_e\}$;

the *right uniformity* $\mathcal R$, generated by the base $\{\{(x,y)\in G\times G:y\in Ux\}:U\in\mathcal \tau_e\}$;

the *two-sided uniformity* $\mathcal L\vee\mathcal R$, generated by the base $\{\{(x,y)\in G\times G:y\in xU\cap Ux\}:U\in\mathcal \tau_e\}$;

the *Roelcke uniformity* $\mathcal L\wedge\mathcal R$, generated by the base $\{\{(x,y)\in G\times G:y\in UxU\}:U\in\mathcal \tau_e\}$.

Here by $\tau_e$ we denote the family of all open neighborhoods of the unit $e$ in $G$.

It is well-known that the completion of $G$ by its two-sided uniformity $\mathcal L\vee\mathcal R$ carries a natural structure of a topological group, and the completion of $G$ by its left (or right) uniform structure carries a structure of a topological semigroup.

**Question.** Has the completion $\bar G$ of a topological group $G$ by its Roelcke uniformity any reasonable algebraic structure? For example, is $\bar G$ a semigroup with continuous right and left shifts by elements of the group $G$?

**Remark.** In Example 4.3 [Uspenskii](https://www.emis.de/proceedings/TopoSym2001/30.pdf) observed that for the homeomorphism group $G=H(2^\omega)$ of the Cantor cube $2^\omega$ the Roelcke completion of $G$ can be identifies with the semigroup of closed relations on $R\subset 2^\omega\times 2^\omega$ having both projections onto $2^\omega$ surjective. This semigroup is not semitopological and not inverse, so there is no hope that the Roelcke completion of any topological group carries the structure of a semitopological (inverse) semigroup. But at least some algebraic structure should be present?